# How to get team id when the bot is installed in personal scope(MS Teams)?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a use case where I need to show following information in my personal application.

1. List of channels in teams where bot is installed.
2. List of users in teams where bot is installed.

I was exploring connector client for the same and came up with following code:-

```
   const credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId, appPassword);
   const connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(credentials, {
        baseUri: serviceUrl
    });
   const token = await credentials.getToken();
   axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${ token }`;

   # To get channels
   const response = await axios.get(
        'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/v3/teams/{teamId}/conversations'
    );

    # To get members
   const users = await connectorClient.conversations.getConversationPagedMembers(teamId);
```

This works perfect as long as I have the teamId.

But the issue I am facing here is with respect to finding `teamId` in personal scope. I install my bot application as follows by choosing the **Add** option.

[image]

As far as I understand, the above installs the bot in the personal scope of the user. Now, in this scenario the team id information is not present in `conversationUpdate` event at all. Please note that this is the first time I am installing the bot in the team, so the data should be available as per Microsoft documentation, but the only information available in channel object is tenant.

```
{
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "28:f5d48856-5b42-41a0-8c3a-c5f944b679b0"
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "2017-02-23T19:38:35.312Z",
    "localTimestamp": "2017-02-23T12:38:35.312-07:00",
    "id": "f:5f85c2ad",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1I9Is_Sx0OIy2rQ7Xz1lcaPKlO9eqmBRTBuW6XzkFtcjqxTjPaCMij8BVMdBcL9L_RwWNJyAHFQb0TRzXgyQvA"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "channel",
        "id": "19:efa9296d959346209fea44151c742e73@thread.skype"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:f5d48856-5b42-41a0-8c3a-c5f944b679b0",
        "name": "SongsuggesterBot"
    },
    "channelData": {
        // for me this object is empty
        "team": {
            "id": "19:efa9296d959346209fea44151c742e73@thread.skype"
        },
        "eventType": "teamMemberAdded",
        "tenant": {
            "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I also tried to install the bot in the team scope by using **Add To Teams** option. In this case it prompts me to select a channel to install, in which I choose `general`.

[image]

Now, I do get the team object inside `channelData` in `onConversationUpdate` and this flow works perfectly fine.

```
{
    "membersAdded": [
        {
            "id": "28:64564f44-dd7c-441a-b427-efcd662f21b5"
        }
    ],
    "type": "conversationUpdate",
    "timestamp": "2021-10-14T13:22:01.6072361Z",
    "id": "f:4ebc9a41-5140-7621-33f5-31d97275ce00",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/in/",
    "from": {
        "id": "29:17ZGff4Pvqz_zSNqEexg-86uBFcB6vnOBZzCwu4_puGdDsrYWCW_DdlB15PrcjC--nLlqD5CwtLMJyzXPY5OSsg",
        "aadObjectId": "eac26e98-104a-4785-87aa-bcf77ea1d7c1"
    },
    "conversation": {
        "isGroup": true,
        "conversationType": "channel",
        "tenantId": "c8fef0de-e240-4456-b523-3285ecc62087",
        "id": "19:y7qDBfGH2jE_Ze6G8mJS_CiWiqCaRFfH77jFZvJ1xgU1@thread.tacv2"
    },
    "recipient": {
        "id": "28:64564f44-dd7c-441a-b427-efcd662f21b5",
        "name": "Trick"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "team": {
            "aadGroupId": "5bc77aa9-9487-49ae-958f-b37b2191e64d",
            "name": "test 5",
            "id": "19:y7qDBfGH2jE_Ze6G8mJS_CiWiqCaRFfH77jFZvJ1xgU1@thread.tacv2"
        },
        "eventType": "teamMemberAdded",
        "tenant": {
            "id": "c8fef0de-e240-4456-b523-3285ecc62087"
        }
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to understand here is that, why is the information not coming in case the bot is installed in personal scope?

I am asking this mainly because without personal scope added for bot(i.e if I keep scope only as `team`), the application does not show for user, inside Apps. But if I allow the scope to be extended to `personal` the user might select that while installing the application and my `teamId` information will not be available to fetch the data, that I need.

This brings to my next question, which is, is there any way in which the default `add` button on the `add app` screen installs the bot in such a way that I get `team` object inside `channelData`, in `conversationUpdate` in every scenario, i.e whether I choose add or add to team?

Is this how it is supposed to behave or am I missing something. Would love to hear some thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you're over thinking this - here's a more simple view:

1. if you install a bot into a **Team**, you'll get a Team Id (and any related channel where it is installed).
2. if you have "personal" scope set up for the bot, then the user *also* has the option to install the bot into "personal" scope. As this implies, they are NOT installing the bot INTO an actual Team - that's why you're not receiving a Team Id. It's not broken - it's entirely correct.

If you don't WANT your bot to be **able** to be installed in personal scope, simply remove that option in your manifest (the "personal" scope) - you have the ability to choose because it depends what you're wanting the user to be able to do with your bot. Some bots only make sense inside a Team, others only in Personal Scope, others only in Group Chat or in a Meeting - you can allow your bot to installed in any/all of these are relevant.

Comment: Let me know here in comments if there's anything still not clear

Comment: This sounds good. If I choose the scope as teams. I cannot find my app under Apps. Is there any way it can show there?

Comment: it think it definitely should show there, but the "add" button drop down/options could be different. The other way to install it would be more relevant anyway though - to go from -within- the Team itself (e.g. "+" button on the list of tabs at the top)

Comment: I am facing a strange behavior here. The mac desktop application and web application do not behave the same way for application installed in team scope. In desktop the application does not show at all inside Apps section, but on web it does. Is this the expected behavior or am I missing something?

I tried adding the app from web app into team scope, I could see across desktop as well as web. But when I tried adding from mac app, its not reflecting either in mac app or web app.

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja - Could you please check with the latest Teams desktop client in MAC machine.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft tried downloading the latest version, same issue

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja - What is your latest Teams version in MAC device?
There may be issue with sync, did you tried to reopen your Teams desktop client & checked it? I think it should work.